# Determining Android Screen Size and Setting View's Size Accordingly

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

Yes, I know this question has been asked dozens of times before. However, when implementing several of the solutions, my app force closes. I have tried doing it on a button click:

```
    //Determine Screen Size and Create Layout Param
    android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int BtnWth = display.getWidth() / 4;
    int BtnHgt = display.getHeight() / 4;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams BtnDim = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BtnWth, BtnHgt);

    // Declare MPC pads
    Button pad1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pad1);

public void onClick(){

    // Set width and height of each pad
    pad1.setLayoutParams(BtnDim);
}
```

And also using the onDraw() method. Both force close on a real Android 3.1 device.

Comment: It's not clear from your code, but it seems you're initializing your values outside the scope of a function. This may happen at a point where the service are not ready, or most probably, where you're layout is not loaded, which may in turn return null values (e.g. for pad1). That kind of behaviour would trigger a Force Close.

Did you try loading your values from a method (onCreate, probably)? Also, you could try-catch your code, and output the Exception details on a trace channel, so you might have a better idea of what could be causing the FC.

Comment: Yes I tried it in onCreate() which I heard may cause the values not to be loaded yet, so then I tried it in onDraw(), where it also force closed. I will try throwing and catching the exception.

Comment: Ok, I've never thrown an exception in Android. How would I go about displaying the results?

Comment: You'd go something like that (sorry, can't input new lines in comments it seems) :
`try { /* your code */ }
catch (Exception e)
{ /* log e.toString() */ }`

You can see an example here: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/Java%20Language/TryCatch.html

Comment: I've tried doing Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Couldnt set dimensions", e); But I don't see any exceptions in Logcat that are from this try-catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code instead to get the screen width and height in pixels:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
```

Make sure you add this to your imports:

```
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
```

Comment: That still produces a force close.

Comment: My guess is that you are getting a force close for a different reason than the code itself.  Investigate the force close with adb.  It will print out a stack trace of exactly what went wrong and why including line numbers in code.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html for info on how to use adb.  You'll want to view the logcat with a command like: adb -s <DEVICE-ID> logcat -v time

Comment: It was a typographical error in my XML file, I left out the "d" in layout_width. Thanks for the adb tip, that will prove useful in the future. Thanks for your help.